# YQL - Not able to return yql results

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

I am trying to return back all the

hyperlinks on the page that I am querying using the rest query.

this is the yql query I used

```
select * from html where url="http://www.stickam.com/videoPlaylist.do?uId=182005497" and xpath="//*[@class='mediaThum']/a"
```

[or the permilink to my yql](http://y.ahoo.it/FXZRR)

here is the code

```
<script src="jquery.1.6.1.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var yql = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stickam.com%2FvideoPlaylist.do%3FuId%3D182005497%22%20and%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2F*%5B%40class%3D'mediaThum'%5D%2Fa%22%20";

    $.get( yql, cbFunc );

    function cbFunc(data) {

    alert(data.query.results.a[0].href);

    }//END FUNC
});//end document.ready
</script>
```

Thanks Anthony.

Answer (score 3):

There are several minor issues, I'll only cover a couple of them.

- **Ask for JSON from YQL**

  You need to tell YQL that you're expecting a JSON formatted response from your query. The YQL url must contain `format=json`.

  ```
  var yql = "http://query.yahooapis...%22%20&format=json";
  ```
- **Ask for JSON from jQuery**

  Use the `$.getJSON` function in place of `$.get`.

Comment: + add callback parameter as "?"

Comment: Any idea, how to scrape web content from http://www.amazon.in/Seiko-Premier-Analog-Blue-Watch/dp/B012T413GO?_encoding=UTF8&ref_=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_i_5c5uzbQG5A293?